# install repository and sync project. android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When opening Android Studio I get the following error messages under messages Gradle Sync:

[image: error messages]

Please help. I need it for my work.

Comment: click the link that says install repo and resync

Comment: i did it and the install is faild

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your project level build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
   }
```

}

as described here: [cannot install repository and sync project - not able to use support libraries 25.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495549/cannot-install-repository-and-sync-project-not-able-to-use-support-libraries-2)