# Cannot install Support repository and sync project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-support-library, build-tools

I am trying to use the support libraries of version 25.2.0 
so I will be able to use the [CameraKit](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5383) library.

I have got the newest build tools downloaded:

[image]

and the support repository: 
[image]

my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Google libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

    // Third party libraries
    compile 'com.flurgle:camerakit:0.9.17'

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
}
```

Problem: 
For each support-library I get the issue:

```
Failed to resolve com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0
```

If I try to click on **Install repository and sync project** nothing happens.

[image]

I have followed that [gradle file](https://github.com/gogopop/CameraKit-Android/blob/master/demo/build.gradle) as an example. Were could be my mistake?

Comment: Update support repository also

Comment: When you click on "Install Repository and sync project", what happens?

Comment: @CommonsWare nothing. When the mouse pointer is over the link it changes to indicate that there is a clickable link. After clicking nothing happens. I have tried **File -> Infalidate caches / Restart**. Unfortunately that did not help

Comment: If you scroll down in the SDK Tools tab (shown in your question), you should see an entry for Android Repository. Does it show that you have the latest version?

Comment: Android Support Repository is downloaded for version 47.0.0? I have added a screenshot to my post.

Comment: I had the same problem with support lib "appcompat-v7:25.4.0", latest at the time of this comment, it dint work for some reason, so I reverted back to a older version "appcompat-v7:25.0.0", you can find the older versions here
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try using the latest support library versions:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.2.1'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
// Third party libraries
compile 'com.flurgle:camerakit:0.9.17'

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
```

here is the detail   [Dependencies](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#custom-tabs)

**EDIT**

Use [Google Maven Repository](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven)

To add them to your build, you need to first include Google's Maven repository in your top-level build.gradle file:

**Project -- build.gradle** (Not app `build.gradle`)

```
 allprojects {
    repositories {
        // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'

       jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: I have applied the changes you suggest and get the issue: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:25.3.1

Comment: the dependency is from official documentation...clean build and make sure you are connected to internet

Comment: @jublikon Since it is not listed in your Android studio, you need to pull the latest. You have not updated in a while.

Comment: puttingin the url for maven in the build.gradle sollve my problem on this... Thanks..

Answer (score 60):

Previously the Android Support Library dependencies were downloaded from Android SDK Manager.

Now all the new versions are available from Google's Maven repository.
In future all android libraries will be distributed through `maven.google.com`

So, by adding the below code to the repositories will build the project.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 43):

I had to add the following to my project level build.gradle. Then the button to install and  worked.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why they wouldn't include this in new projects.

Answer (score 16):

Make sure to put it under `allprojects`! My mistake was to put it under `buildscript`.

DON'T DO THIS:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
         maven {
             url 'https://maven.google.com' //don't put it here
         }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}
```

BUT INSTEAD DO THIS:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com' //put it here
        }
    }
}
```